# Как проверить какие флаги потока вывода установлены

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Есть задание по с++:

> Проверить какие флаги потока вывода установлены и заменить попарно на
>   левое выравнивание на правое выравнивание (и наоборот) убрать + перед
>   числом, если установлен и установить, если сброшен.

Разобрался как изменить выравнивание и установить +.
Но не могу разобраться как проверить какие флаги уже установлены.
Где можно подробнее об этом почить или посмотреть примеры? 
Может кто-то может показать пример кода.

Answer (score 2):

Собственно есть такая функция-член для потоков, которая так и называется [`flags`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/flags/). Можно как установить новые флаги, так и считать имеющиеся.

Проверить какой-то конкретный флаг на наличие можно с помощью битовой операции "и". Например, на флаг `showpos`:

```
auto flags = stream.flags();
if (flags & std::ios::showpos)
{ 
   // showpos установлен
}
```